# Delete statement SQL joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Can anyone please tell me how to write a delete statement for the following query:

```
      SELECT     a.UserID, b.UserEmailAddress
      FROM  tblUserProgramme AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN

      tblUser AS b ON b.UserID = a.UserID LEFT OUTER JOIN
      tblWorkGroup AS c ON c.WorkGroupID = b.WorkGroupID

      WHERE(a.ProgrammeID = 59) AND (a.UserID NOT IN

          (SELECT     UserID FROM tblUser AS a WHERE (WorkGroupID IN
             (SELECT     WorkGroupID FROM tblWorkGroup WHERE                          
             (WorkGroupName  LIKE  '%Insight%') OR (WorkGroupName LIKE '%Other%'))))) 

      AND (b.UserEmailAddress NOT IN
            (SELECT     email FROM          tmpUsers))

      ORDER BY b.UserEmailAddress
```

SERVER is SQL Server 2005

Comment: which database? SQL server, mysql?

Comment: have edited the question

Comment: Confusing.... could you please add bit more detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax is DB specific.. 
For most of tha databases this should work , if you want to delete from tblUserProgramme

```
DELETE A
FROM tblUserProgramme AS a 
 .....
```

Answer (score 4):

Query would be

```
Delete from 

 ( 
 SELECT     a.UserID, b.UserEmailAddress
  FROM  tblUserProgramme AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN
  tblUser AS b ON b.UserID = a.UserID LEFT OUTER JOIN
  tblWorkGroup AS c ON c.WorkGroupID = b.WorkGroupID
  WHERE(a.ProgrammeID = 59) AND (a.UserID NOT IN
(SELECT     UserID FROM tblUser AS a WHERE (WorkGroupID IN
(SELECT     WorkGroupID FROM tblWorkGroup WHERE (WorkGroupName  LIKE           
'%Insight%') OR (WorkGroupName LIKE '%Other%'))))) AND (b.UserEmailAddress NOT IN
(SELECT     email FROM          tmpUsers))
ORDER BY b.UserEmailAddress
) a
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, in SQL Server, you can delete all records which match a given SQL query as follows, provided your SELECT only returns columns from a single table:

```
DELETE x
FROM
(
   -- Any query which returns data from a single table, that you wish to delete
) x;
```

Or, using a CTE:

```
;WITH x as 
(
   -- Any query which returns data from a single table, that you wish to delete
)
DELETE x;
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for your quick answers:) There were a quite a few answers right, but had to pick the first one:)

As Joe G Joseph has mentioned,
this is what i did

```
DELETE a
from dbo.tblUserProgramme a
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblUser b ON b.UserID = a.UserID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblWorkGroup c ON c.WorkGroupID = b.WorkGroupID
where a.ProgrammeID = 59 AND 
a.UserID  NOT IN (SELECT UserID  FROM tblUser a WHERE a.WorkGroupID IN
(SELECT WorkGroupID FROM tblWorkGroup
WHERE WorkGroupName like '%Insight%' OR WorkGroupName like '%Other%')) 
 AND b.UserEmailAddress NOT IN(SELECT email FROM tmpUsers)
```